# How to understand the array length

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method like this:

```
private static byte [] rec (byte []...n) {
    int nob = n[0].length - 1;
    System.out.println("The length of this is : " + nob);
}
```

In my main method, I'm calling it like this:

```
byte [][] shar = one.calculatethresholdscheme(secret, n,k, new SecureRandom());

byte [][] sharesToViewSecret = new byte[] []{shar[0],shar[1],shar[3],shar[6]};

// when we say n[0], n[2], n[3] we are talking for the rows of byte [] [] n which keeps the index from 0 to 7
byte [] recoverSecret = one.rec(sharesToViewSecret);
```

And then when I print it out it gives me a result I was not expecting. Can anyone explain what `n[0].length - 1;` means?

Actually I was expecting to get the result `4` as I have used four `shar[...]` as method arguments but it gives me the result `11` which is actually the number of bytes of my file.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. As it stands I can't understand anything about you code, right or wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration

```
private static byte [] rec (byte []...n)
```

Is [(somewhat) equivalent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) to

```
private static byte [] rec (byte [][] n)
```

In your `rec` method, `n` is an array of arrays of bytes. `n[0]` is the first of these arrays.

When you're calling `rec`, the first element of `n` is `shar[0]`, and so `n[0].length` is giving you `shar[0].length`. If you want the number of elements in `n`, you just want `n.length`.

Answer (score -2):

I am pretty sure that the `n[0].length - 1;` means take the length of the 0th term in n array, then it will subtract 1 from the length. For example if the 0th term was "Hello" the length would be "4" then the code would subtract 1 from 4 and get 3. Keep in mind that in java and other languages you start counting at 0 not 1.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Length of "Hello" would be 5 not 4.

Comment: -1: 1. Strings are not represented as bytes or even character arrays in Java, please don't confuse this learner. 2. Your math is wrong as callyalater pointed out. Try just using an actual byte array example.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, and wouldn't Hello be 4 because H =0, e = 1, l = 2, l = 3 and o = 4?

Comment: No. When counting elements in an array, Java starts from `1`. When accessing elements in an array, Java starts from `0`. The `length` attribute in Java is used to tell the number of elements in an array the same way we would count ourselves. In general, the `a.length - 1` idiom is used to help identify the index of the last element in the array which is valuable in bounds checking. What you said with `H=0, e=1, ...` is true for *indices*, but not for array length.